# Adding node to end of singly linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to add a node to the end of a singly linked list but am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped error)

```
void slist_add_back(struct slist *l, char *str) {
    struct snode *temp;

    do {
        l->front = l->front->next;
        l->counter++;
    } while (l->front !=NULL);

    l->counter++;
    temp = (struct snode *)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    l->back = l->front;
    l->back->next = temp;
    l->back = temp;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be incrementing the counter quite a bit for only adding one element.

Comment: This is more C code than it is C++.

Comment: Does `front` represent the front of your list?  If so, you don't want to be changing it just because you're adding another element here.

Comment: yes front represent the front of my list but I am trying to traverse the list so I can enter in the new node?

Comment: this code makes *zero* sense. I've found about 10 bugs. I'm not kidding.

Comment: Are you sure it is a singly linked list? `front` _and_ `back` seems to suggest that it is a doubly linked list.

Comment: @ssm: there's also `next`. so `back` probably points to the last item.

Comment: thank you all very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
do{
      l->front = l->front->next;
      l->counter++;

   }while(l->front !=NULL);
```

At the end `l->front` is null. Now `l->back = l->front;` implies `l->back` is also null. So this assignment is wrong:

```
l->back->next = temp; // causing segfault
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems lies here:

```
do
{
    l->front = l->front->next;
    l->counter++;
} while(l->front !=NULL);
```

You are modifying the list instead of iterating it.  It should be something like this:

```
snode* curr = l->front;
if (curr == NULL) // first element
{
    front = new snode(str);
    return;
}

while (curr->next != NULL)
{
    ++curr;
}
curr->next = new snode(str); // or the malloc version if you want to stay in C
```

Comment: this is C, there's no `new`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath His original tag was C++ (hence my comment both on the OP and in the code example).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is something what you want?
I dont really understand what your code is doing, sorry.

```
void slist_add_back(struct slist *l, char *str)
{


   struct snode *currentNode = l->front;
   if(currentNode!=NULL)
   {
      struct snode *temp = (struct snode *)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
      while(currentNode->next!=NULL)
      {
         l->counter++;//although i dont know why
         currentNode = currentNode->next;
      }


      l->counter++;//again
      currentNode->next = temp;
      l->back = temp;
      temp->next = NULL;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your code roughly should look like:

```
void slist_add_back(struct slist *l, char *str)
{
    struct snode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    temp->next = NULL;
    //note: store str... (strdup?)

    if (! l->back) {
        l->front = temp;
    } else {
        l->back->next = temp;
    }
    l->back = temp;
    l->counter++;
}
```

Note: Based on your code I would be really surprised if the rest wouldn't be full of bugs, so except crashes even if this part is fixed...

Pick a debugger, and check what your code *really* does.